# Problem with fitting

Tags: list-manipulation, fitting

If I have the following data (**I have updated the data**):

```
  data={{{60, 1852.94}, {65, 178.035}, {70, 7.97143}, {75, 48.9479}, {80, 
  133.561}, {85, 8.65079}, {87, 1.78915}}
```

How can I fit it to the following equation?

```
eq = 1/((x*c1)/((Exp[B1/(x - T0)])^0.75)*(1 - Exp[((Tm - x)*c2)/Tm^2])) /. {T0 -> 259.246,B1 -> 2595.89, Tm -> 88.2 + 273.15}
```

I am trying the following:

```
  fun[x_] = NonlinearModelFit[data,eq, {c1, c2}, x] // Normal (*c1=732975, c2=2.65721*10^6*)
```

Which gives me an erroneous `c1` and `c2` of `c1=732975` & `c2=2.65721*10^6`. When I do it in excel it gives me a `c1` of -65514626.34 and a `c2` of 68.4 which fits the data relative well. Why mathematica is not fitting the data or finding the correct `c1` and `c2` values?

Comment: Try to plot this: `Show[{
  ListPlot[data],
  Plot[(E^(2595.89/(-259.246 + x)))^0.75/(c1 (1 - E^(5.092118394960718*^-6 c2 (443.15 - x))) x) /. {c1 ->313634, c2 -> -8434.47}, {x, First[data][[1]], Last[data][[1]]},
    PlotRange -> All]`. It shows that the values of c1 and c2 you obtained from excel yield a very bad fit, if any.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch thank you for you comment. Then what would the best fit be? and why Mathematica cannot find it?

Comment: Often such things indicate that the model is not optimal. I would try to think about another to fit the data.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I have updated the data. I think the reason it was not working is because the y axis of the data was in log scale. I have updated the data now. I think now the c1 and c2 values that I found in excel are the ones that fit the data but still Mathematica does not find it

Comment: I do not see that. Try to look at the plot (the code from my first comment) with your new data.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch try for example: `fun[x_] = 
  NonlinearModelFit[
    Tinficryst /. {x_, y_} -> {x + 273.15, y}, {eq, c1 == -65514626.3392678, c2 == 68.393062008793}, {c1, c2}, x] // Normal;` you will see that by making `c1` and `c2` those values the fit are good. However, Mathematica does not find the value of  `-65514626.339267` for `c1` or the value of `68.393062008793` for `c2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the response and predictor variables are both positive and structure of the model, one of the coefficients (`c1` and `c2`) needs to be negative and the other needs to be positive.  Excel's answer at least has that property but I don't see why you say that the Excel answer fits the data relatively well.

```
data = {{60, 1852.94}, {65, 178.035}, {70, 7.97143}, {75, 48.9479}, {80, 133.561}, 
  {85, 8.65079}, {87, 1.78915}};

eq = 1/((x*c1)/((Exp[B1/(x - T0)])^0.75)*(1 - Exp[((Tm - x)*c2)/Tm^2])) /. 
  {T0 -> 259.246, B1 -> 2595.89, Tm -> 88.2 + 273.15};

excel = {c1 -> -65514626.34, c2 -> 68.4}; 
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[eq /. excel, {x, 60, 87}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Data and Excel fit]

If you start off with estimates of the coefficients with opposite signs, then `NonlinearModelFit` finds a better fit.

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, eq, {{c1, -1}, {c2, 1}}, x, MaxIterations -> 10000];
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {c1 -> 0.000589194, c2 -> -0.000841265} *)
nlm["EstimatedVariance"]^0.5
(* 543.51 *)
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All], Plot[nlm[x], {x, 60, 87}]]
```

[image: Data and better fit]

Because the estimators of the coefficients given the data and model are nearly perfectly correlated (look at `nlm["CorrelationMatrix"]`), there is a great deal of numerical instability.  In fact, just setting `c2` to some arbitrary number and fitting with just `c1` gives an even better fit:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, eq /. c2 -> 1, {{c1, -1}}, x, MaxIterations -> 10000];
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {c1 -> -4.95197*10^-7} *)
nlm["EstimatedVariance"]^0.5
(* 496.162 *)
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All], Plot[nlm[x], {x, 60, 87}]]
```

[image: Even better fit]

But all fits are horrible.  To paraphrase Bullwinkle the Moose:  "You need a better model."